# How to call a custom function before jquery ajax success is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, backbone.js

I am working on a mobile app that uses jQuery and BackboneJS. Most of the ajax calls are done using jQuery's native `$.ajax` function and some are done using Backbone's `fetch()` and `save()` functions. Now I understand that Backbone too, at a low level, calls jQuery's `$.ajax` function for xhr requests. What I want to know is, how can I perform some computation on my response (received from ajax calls) before actually calling the success handler?

So what I want to know is, is there some way I can extend some jquery function such that it will execute the custom code I want, before calling the ajax success handler?

Comment: Use the success callback function, from this point execution is synchronous and you can return false if you don't want to continue.

Comment: No. I guess I couldn't make myself clear. I want to execute some function on my response whether it is called using `$.ajax` or Backbone's `fetch` and `save` method. If I use the success handler then I'll have to edit my entire code to run that function in each success handler. That is not something I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use global Ajax events: http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/

```
$(document).bind("ajaxSuccess", function(){
// code here
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
// code here
 });
```

However, I'm not sure about the event order, I didn't find you is the event precedence between local and global handlers.

Comment: See, the thing is, I cannot handle all my events by using a global ajax success handler like you show. And writing a custom handler for each of the request is also not a good idea. So I was hoping to find a way to extend native jquery functionality in such a way that it processes the xhr response the way I want, and then call the respective success handlers as it normally does. Am I clear? Because I don't think I'm doing a good job in explaining what I want.

Comment: I think that I understand you, But you can mix global and local handlers, that is, use the local handler for the "local" task and the global for the "common" tasks that need to be executed every time